# Android: upload image with json

Tags: android, json, node.js, bitmap

I am trying to upload a Bitmap from my Android app to my NodeJS server. My Bitmap has some data (Json) which has to be uploaded in the same (POST) message. I saw that it is possible by:

- Multipart form data.
- Image encoding (converting the image to string) on the app side and decoding on the server side.

Is there a better way? Has anyone familiar with a good guide to perform such an upload?

Comment: Image encoding could make a very large string, and it will be bigger than the original image, in my opinion multipart form data is the way to go.

Comment: @ Boldijar Paul  Should i use the MultipartEntity object or just the regular DataOutputStream?

Comment: You can code all yourself. Or find ready code all over this site. Or use a library. If you want to use json (as you say in the subject) you cannot use multipart and have to encode the image data base64 which increases size with 30%.

Comment: Multipart would be easier and better solution than sending it as json which would require base64 encode then decode also parse the json which blocks the nodejs event loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. This is a code that i wrote (merge of several answers) for the Multipart upload. If there are any problems with the code please let me know.

```
    // create a url object
    URL url = new URL(mGlobalUrl + localUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    //--start--
    //Deal with data
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);           //key
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(value);    //value
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    //Deal with image
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);           //key
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadFile\"; filename=\"" + "image1" + "\"" + lineEnd);
    //outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + fileMimeType + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(imagePath);   //value
    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
    //--end--

    // receive response as inputStream
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        // convert input stream to string
        if (inputStream != null) {
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        }
        else {

            Log.d(TAG, "sendPostRequest: Error - input stream is null");
            result = "{}";
        }
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    conn.disconnect();
```

For the server side (NodeJS) I used the Formidable module (I am not sure whether it is deprecated or not), you can find some more information regarding this mode [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

```
upload_image = function(req, res, next) {

//create new incoming form object
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

//parse the request using formidable module
form.parse(req, function(error, fields, files) {

    //check if error occurred during the parse
    if (error) {
        ...some code
        return;
    }

    //save the data received in the request
    ...some code 
});

//check for errors during the transmission
form.on('error', function(err) {
    ...some code
    return;
});

//check for the end of the transmission
form.on('end', function(error, fields, files) {
    //save the temporary location of the uploaded image file
    var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;

    //save the file name of the uploaded image file
    var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;

    //save the file
    ...some code

    //update the database
    ...some code
};
```

Comment: Hey @MaxZ could you please post code how you handling the image? it can be nice to know which library you use, as lots of libraries exist but most of them have deprecated methods and conflicting with android natives.

Comment: @nsgulliver Done.